# Enabling comments in IBM Content Navigator document viewer

Tags: filenet, ibm-content-navigator

I am trying to enable the layout Comment Button in the viewer,

[image: screenshot]

So far I try to enable it with **ContentViewer.js** by changing the disable property to false but it keeps turning disable, so what make this disable, so how can I enable this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Socical Collaboration Add-ons for the Object Store. (via ACCE or FEM).

Comment: Hi @swepss , i have installed them but this button didn't activated . for this client we did a custom viewer as the solution back then , but its still good to know a valid answer for this :)

Comment: @Archangle Read the documentation "Configuring IBM FileNet Content Manager repositories to display comments, likes, downloads, and tags"  at link http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEUEX_2.0.3/com.ibm.installingeuc.doc/eucco069.htm